# Categorical xaxis without showing the numbers in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

My xaxis is formed out of a range (0,100). Instead of showing the numbers I would like to show a text, like "item1" every let's say 20 ticks. So instead of the first 20 ticks it should be "item1", instead of the following 20 - "item2" etc.

```
x=range(0,100)
y=[5 for i in x]
p = figure()
p.circle(x=x, y=y)
show(p)
```

[image]

What I would like is instead of 0,20,40 etc. to have the items of a list:
`categorical=["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"]` and do not show the numbers at all.

I've tried with `p = figure(x_range=categorical)` but then not all the dots appear - only 1 per category appears.

I've also tried with factors:

```
factors = [("item1", 1), ("item1", 2) ....("item2", 21)... ]
x_range = FactorRange(*factors)
```

But then all the numbers appear and it ends up with something like this if you have more than 1000 numbers:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it with:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {0: "type1", "20": "type2"...}
p.xaxis[0].ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=[0, 20 ...])
```